# Can I easily reformat a document to place figure legends on a separate page?

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I am submitting an article to a journal with the following requirement:

> Figure legends should be listed one after the other, as part of the text document, separate from the figure files.

Currently, my figure captions are in the format

```
\caption[short caption]{full caption}
```

And I only want the `full caption` to appear.

Can I insert the complete figure legends in a list of figures, and exclude them from the figure itself?

(Edit: without changing the behavior of table captions?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems be what you're after...

Using the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) you can modify captions by removing the label separator. Additionally, I've redefined `\caption` so you only need to specify a single (mandatory) argument. (**Edit**: Moved redefinition to after `\begin{document}`.) `oldcaption` gives the default behavior of `caption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{letltxmacro}% http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{none}{} \captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=none,textformat=none}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering \includegraphics{image1}
  \caption[Unused first legend]{This is a first legend}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption[a, b, and c]{The first $3$ letters of the alphabet}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \hline 
  a & b & c \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering \includegraphics{image2}
  \caption[Unused second legend]{This is a second legend}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provides filler text, while the `demo` option to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) is just meant for this MWE example, since it doesn't have images included. Captions are just typeset as `Figure <num>`, while the actual figure caption is included in the "List of Figures".

Comment: The example code will issue the warning "Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already redefined by a document class or package which is unknown to the caption package.". So IMHO one better put the redefinition of `\caption` inside `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: Agreed, or move the `\renewcommand{\caption}{...}` to after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: An alternative option would be dropping the redefinition of `\caption` and using `\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{none}{}
\captionsetup{labelsep=none,textformat=none}` instead.

Comment: Werner, if you move the `\renewcommand` after `\begin{document}` you should move the `\LetLtxMacro`, too. Otherwise your code will drop the redefinition of `\caption` done by the caption package.

Comment: @Werner this is a great start, but your example does not work when using \caption[short caption]{long caption}. Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: @David: In `\caption[short caption]{long caption}`, what would `short caption` and `long caption` be used for? At the moment, I've completely disregarded `short caption` and only put `long caption` in the LoF. Where would you want to put `short caption`? Or is it just so your original code can compile without problem, since that's easily fixable?

Comment: @Werner it is just so my original code can compile without problem.

Comment: @David: I've updated my code. The only change is actually: `renewcommand{\caption}[2][]{\oldcaption[#2]{}}` which now allows for an optional first argument to `\caption[..]{...}`. It is not used *at all* in the document (it's discarded).

Comment: The actual version 3.2c of the caption package has a new option `textformat=empty`, so `\usepackagelabelsep=none,textformat=empty]{caption}` should do the trick, too.

Comment: @David: That's not a problem. You can erase your recent comments to keep this area clean. I'll do the same.

Answer (score 1):

In the following solution the list of captions is printed at the end of the document. It has the advantage that it's sufficient to comment out the added code in order to have the normal version of the document printed. In the final list only "long captions" will be printed, while the normal list will have the short ones.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{shorttoc,letltxmacro,etoolbox}
\LetLtxMacro{\ORIcaption}{\caption}
\renewcommand{\caption}{\@dblarg{\x@caption}}
\def\x@caption[#1]#2{\ORIcaption[\shortcaption{#1}\longcaption{#2}]{#2}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\shortcaption}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\longcaption}{}
\let\ORIlistoffigures\listoffigures
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
  \begingroup
    \def\shortcaption##1{##1} \def\longcaption##1{}
    \anothertableofcontents[lof]{\jobname}{\listfigurename}{1}
  \endgroup}
\newcommand{\listofcaptions}{\newpage
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \begingroup
    \def\shortcaption##1{} \def\longcaption##1{##1}%
    \def\listfigurename{Captions to figures}%
    \def\l@figure##1##2{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}{##1}{}}%
    \patchcmd{\@dottedtocline}{\hbox{.}}{}{}{}%
    \listoffigures
    \endgroup}
\AtEndDocument{\listofcaptions}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
X
\caption{This has only a long caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
Y
\caption[This short one]{This has also a short caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```