# Add a figure title and x-axis label to a figure matrix created using pdfpages

Tags: graphics, captions, pdfpages

#### Background

I previously asked: [Can I convert a 16 page pdf into an 8x2 matrix in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7891/1783)

I ended up creating a 3x5 matrix of images from a 15 page pdf by compiling a document "foo.tex":

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                          
\usepackage{pdfpages}                                                                            
\begin{document}                                                                                 
\includepdf[landscape = false,                                                                   
pages={1-15},                                                                                    
nup=3x8,                                                                                         
delta={10 10}]{myplots.pdf}                                                          
\end{document}
```

Which gives the document foo.pdf:

[image]

I have used the `caption` package to place captions on a separate page, as described in the [answer to a separate question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30480/1783) by putting this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}% http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro
\captionsetup{labelsep=none}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{none}{} \captionsetup{labelsep=none,textformat=none}
```

And then include foo.pdf in my manuscript as a figure with the following command:

```
\begin{figure}[p]
  \caption{This is my caption that will end up on another page}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{foo.pdf}
  \end{center}
  \label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

#### Question

Now, I need to add a title and an x-axis label to the overall figure (not to the individual plots), how can I do this?

I have looked in the [pgfpages](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) documentation, and could not find any such feature.

#### Updates / What I have tried

using [overpic](/questions/tagged/overpic), as suggested in the [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20792/1783) suggested by @percusse would work after adding `ofset=10mm,10mm` to the `pdfpages` command, except that it is not clear how to rotate the text 90 degrees for the x-axis. I have come up with a temporary "good-enough" solution and [posted this as an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61271/1783)

Comment: @jake to the overall figure; I created the individual figures in the R ggplot2 package, and I can manipulate the individual plots pretty easily.

Comment: What is the relation between `pdfpages` and the x-axis label ? I think your solution is not related to plots per se. Why not using `\caption{X-axis label}`.

Comment: You might need to use PSTricks or TikZ to place the figures in a coordinate axes.

Comment: @percusse The relation with `pdfpages` is only that I used it to create the figure, and I don't know if the solution is in the figure creation or when including it in the main document. Please re-tag as appropriate. I don't use caption mainly because the caption is on a separate page, as per publishers' instructions using the caption package, as described in [the answer to a related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30477/1783)

Comment: @percusse I have updated my question to reflect the use of the `caption` package.

Comment: @Forgiver I have updated the tags to include [tag:pstricks] and [tag:tikz-pgf]

Comment: I think you can just annotate the image and use your regular solution. One possibility is to put it in a TikZ node but there are other ways. See what I mean in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20792/how-to-superimpose-latex-on-a-picture or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20792/how-to-superimpose-latex-on-a-picture Note that this will happen inside the figure environment so no complication would be visible to caption or other mechanisms. If this is a suitable solution then it's quite simple to achieve.

Comment: @percusse thanks for the links, but you only posted one link two times - did you intend to post a link to a different question?

Comment: Oopa sorry here is the other one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Comment: Have you try the `pagecommand` option of `\includepdf`? In its argument, you can add all the necessary content (using `overpic` for example).

Comment: @PolGab I am not looking to add anything to each page in the source pdf, just to add text to the overall figure.

Comment: @David `pagecommand` option is used to add something to the overall figure. Look at my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with `pagecommand` option of `\includepdf` (and `picture`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[landscape = false,
pages={1-15},
offset=-5mm -15mm,
nup=3x8,
delta={10 10},
pagecommand={
\begin{picture}(0,0)
  \put (100,100) {\normalsize{\sffamily{This is my manually-centered title}}}
\end{picture}
},
]{myplots.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Same solution using `tikz` to center and rotate nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[landscape = false,
pages={1-15},
offset=-5mm -15mm,
nup=3x8,
delta={10 10},
pagecommand={
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[font=\large\bfseries]
    at ([yshift=-8mm]current page.north)
    {This is my centered title};
    \node[font=\large\bfseries,rotate=90]
    at ([xshift=1in]current page.west)
    {Y Label...};
    \node[font=\large\bfseries]
    at ([yshift=-6cm]current page.center)
    {X Label...};
  \end{tikzpicture}
},
]{myplots.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Here's the result (using a beamer document instead of `myplots.pdf`):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the hacky answer that I have come up with, but it requires generating the figure first (foo.pdf) and then the figure with the title (foo_title.pdf); foo_title.pdf is the final figure to be incorporated into the manuscript.

1. generate foo.pdf with `pdfpages[offset=-5mm -15mm]`

   ```
   \documentclass{article}                                                                          
   \usepackage{pdfpages}                                                                            
   \begin{document}                                                                                 
   \includepdf[landscape = false,                                                                   
   pages={1-15},
   offset=-5mm -15mm,                                                                                    
   nup=3x8,                                                                                         
   delta={10 10}]{myplots.pdf}                                                          
   \end{document}
   ```
2. generate foo_title using the [overpic](/questions/tagged/overpic) package and [geometry](/questions/tagged/geometry) package to remove margins:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[percent]{overpic}
   \usepackage{geometry}
   \geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=0cm,bmargin=0cm,lmargin=0cm,rmargin=0cm}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{overpic}{foo.pdf}
    \put (18,98) {\normalsize{\sffamily{This is my manually-centered title}}}
   \end{overpic}
   \end{document}
   ```

   Here is the resulting foo_title.pdf:

   [image]
3. Include foo_title.pdf in manuscript

This solution lacks the following desirable features:

- do this in one, rather than three separate tex (and four pdf) files
- x-axis label with rotated text
- automatically centered title and x-axis label